# Cancel "allman" brace-style when 'implicit-arrow-linebreak' is "beside"

Tags: node.js, eslint

I was looking at similar issues, but it seems my case is somewhat special.

I'm wanting to enforce the "allman" `brace-style`, but also want to set the `implicit-arrow-linebreak` to "beside", as pictured:

```
{
  // ...
  "rules": {
    "brace-style": [2, "allman"],
    "implicit-arrow-linebreak": [2, "as-beside"],
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Now I have this snippet:

```
this.fetchMeta()
    .then(metadata => {
        this.meta = metadata;

        this.initiateInterval();
    }).catch(this.destroy);
```

The [first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNVw2.png) I get is regarding the `brace-style`, which I understand can be fixed by creating a newline. Trying to fix this causes [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x20HW.png), making the `this` keyword unavailable (which I need). Declaring `this` as `self` before-hand does not work.

How do I cancel out the "allman" `brace-style` when `implicit-arrow-linebreak` is set to "beside"?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? Seeing the same behavior and would like to override this behavior.

Comment: Ahh this was a long time ago. I think I couldn't figure it out and just ran with how eslint forced me to do it, or after some time it fixed itself? I'm not sure.